# Error updating metadata via Apex

Tags: apex, metadata-api, custom-metadata, metadata.operations

I have an issue, I created a CMT to store a token for a integration with thirdparty system, with the SA user works fine, but it doesn't work for other users, when I check the debug logs I saw this error: "System.NoAccessException: Not allowed to install or modify metadata via Apex"

This is the code to update the CMT:

```
Metadata.CustomMetadata customMetadata =  new Metadata.CustomMetadata();
        customMetadata.fullName = 'PDB_Token.Token';
        customMetadata.label = 'Token';

        Metadata.CustomMetadataValue customFieldDate = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();
        customFieldDate.field = 'Fecha_Token__c';
        system.debug('#####token:');
        system.debug(t);
        customFieldDate.value = System.now().addSeconds(Integer.valueOf(t.expires_in));

        customMetadata.values.add(customFieldDate);

        Metadata.CustomMetadataValue customFieldToken = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();
        customFieldToken.field = 'Token__c';
        customFieldToken.value = t.access_token;

        customMetadata.values.add(customFieldToken);

        Metadata.DeployContainer mdContainer = new Metadata.DeployContainer();
        mdContainer.addMetadata(customMetadata);

        CustomMetadataCallback callback = new CustomMetadataCallback();

         Id jobId = Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment(mdContainer, callback);
```

I already gave these permissions: "Modify Metadata Through Metadata API Functions" and also I enabled the CMT that store the token.

So any of you knows what other permission I need to assign to the users so they can update the CMT via Apex?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Metadata API doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_modify_metadata_perm.htm?q=permissions)

> Users must have the **Customize Application** permission to create, update, and delete metadata records. Thereafter, users with the **Modify Metadata Through Metadata API Functions** permission can edit metadata (including Apex) through Metadata API even if they don’t also have the Modify All Data permission.

Note, I found this [GitHub andyinthecloud package useful to avoid some custom code](https://andyinthecloud.com/2017/08/29/introducing-custom-metadata-services/)

Comment: Hi @cropedy I tried it but didn't work

Comment: this might be a clue: http://disq.us/p/2spaeit

Answer (score 2):

I am running into a nearly identical issue in my org that started just days ago.

**cropredy** posted a link to [A Possible Clue](https://unofficialsf.com/save-and-update-custom-metadata-records-using-flow/#comment-6089093381)

After looking at this post and the comments, there was some additional information provided in the first comment that I personally tested in a sandbox and found an answer to your question.

I was originally assigning the **Customize Application** and **Modify Metadata Through Metadata API Functions** permissions through a permission set that I had created. I received the same error:

```
System.NoAccessException: Not allowed to install or modify metadata via Apex
```

### **The Workaround**

The only way I was able to bypass this issue was by creating a duplicate copy of the profile which the user was assigned, and assigned the **Customize Application** and **Modify Metadata Through Metadata API Functions** permissions to the profile itself.

After assigning the original user the newly created profile with the additional permissions, my code worked as expected.

### UPDATE(S)

2/21/20230 - I have opened a Case with Salesforce to report what I believe is a bug. I will keep this responses updated with the findings of the Case.

Comment: kudos for reproducing -- sadly, this workaround goes against the grain of not using Profiles (these are being deprecated in 2026) and we can only hope SFDC will fix this issue before then

Comment: I agree completely. I attempted to open a ticket with Salesforce to report the issue, but due to some "performance degradation". I'll continue to try and open a ticket for the issue.

Comment: I'd also suggest @mentioning Cheryl Feldman, the PM for Profiles; she can be found on Twitter at https://twitter.com/CherFeldman.

Comment: Thanks to all for your replies, I made a schedule class to get the token with a sa profile as executor the schedule class, so this is the workaround I found to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000smLF8AAM/%7E) with 6 reports, currently tagged as Solution in Progress

Answer (score 0):

I suffered the same problem - couldn't save Custom Metadata records using APEX.

So I opened a Case with the Partner Support Team and they have enabled the Aloha Perm on our packaging org, and ta-da, I don't need the checkbox 'Deploy Metadata from Non-Certified Package Versions via Apex' ticked anymore for the latest version of the App!

Thank you to all of the above subscribers for putting me on the right track.